# Development environment/process for systems (OS) programming?

Tags: operating-system, development-environment, kernel

What is a typical development environment/process used for operating systems programming. I am currently taking an OS course through my university where we are playing around in the MINIX OS (e.g. modifying the scheduler, adding new services, etc) which is great fun, but the development process is a bit painful/annoying. Currently I have MINIX running on VirtualBox on my local machine (MacBook Pro 13"), and each time I test my changes I have to recompile an image which takes about 10 - 20 minutes and reboot, sometimes only to have the kernel panic on me.

I am wondering if this is just something people who do OS development live with, or is there a better way?